# Read Other threads warnings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, logging, network-programming, mariadb

I am facing a possible memory leak in Mariadb. I hope reading the warning messages from all the thread could lead me to what is causing it. The problem is warning are not logged anywhere. I can see from the network traffic dump that some threads have a high number of warnings but I can not access them. The application using the database is not logging anything related to database either. How can I read all the threads warnings. I have full access to the server.

[I want to have access to these warnings, I don't have any control on the app node to log them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUvxW.png)

Comment: What warnings what lets you think there is a possible memory leak?

Comment: There used to be huge number of failed attempts for inserting data into the database but they were failing because of a value problem. I am suspicious of them @RaymondNijland

Comment: You should share table structures, the inserts and the warnings you get. And server version

Comment: I am using Mariadb 10.2.18. I don't know which database and tables are causing it. I found one of the schema problems by accident and it improved the situation I don't get any warning thats the problem. This is a very busy server with a few different DBs and I can't enable GENERAL_LOG on it to see what is going on. @RaymondNijland

Comment: "Can't enable GENERAL LOG"?  Or "don't want to"?  Turn it on briefly; grab the results for further study.

Comment: It doesn't happen regularly and when it happens it allocates a big amount of memory (2GB) and It has been never returned. I am suspicious of insert queries which went wrong or a very long transaction that was never committed because of an exception in application or something. I don't have any access to modify the application now but I need to see those warnings. please check the photo in the question. I got it using the network dump. @RickJames

Comment: What is port 36410?  Is this in a router/VIP/load-balancer/other?  That .png looks like a network issue, not MariaDB.  Look for a network sniffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the leak. Whenever there was a jump in memory usage, there was a jump at number of subqueries. By disabling subquery cache problem was solved. Still the root cause is unknown.